# Calculating 95% confidence interval for multi-class predictions

Tags: confidence-interval, multi-class

I have a multi-class classification model that predicts
the following probabilities for 4 classes in 3 test cases:

```
1. (0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2)  
2. (0.01, 0.09, 0.5, 0.4) 
3. (0.55, 0.25, 0.1, 0.1)
```

How to calculate [95% confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) for prediction of each class in every test case?

Thanks!